# How to add data from a list to a new[]

Tags: c#

I have a list `o` that has strings:

```
    "Hist 2368#19:00:00#20:30:00#Large Conference Room",
    "Hist 2368#09:00:00#10:30:00#Large Conference Room",
```

I want to add those strings to this:

```
var lines = new[]
{  
    "Meeting#19:00:00#20:30:00#Conference", 
};
```

How would I use the data from the list `o` and insert it into `lines`?

Comment: List.ToArray: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x303t819(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You probably shouldn't be using an array.

Comment: `lines = o.ToArray()` would give you an array from the list, but it will not change the contents like you did.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Array are be nature, fixed-length.  You need to create a new array, and assign it to `lines`.

```
lines = lines.Concat(o).ToArray();
```

Alternately,

```
lines = o.AddRange(lines).ToArray();
```

UPDATE: Fixed dumb mistake.

Comment: I think the second line should have `AddRange`, +1.

Answer (score 1):

Since Lines is already an array, you'll need to merge the values into your list first:

```
foreach (var item in lines)
    o.Add(item);
```

Then change o to an Array:

```
o.ToArray();  ///returns String[] with all three values.
```

You can also use .concat() as others have pointed out, which will internally do the same.

Answer (score 1):

An additional thing to consider is the `lines` variable has an `Array(T)` type which is a fixed size, so you must either allocate enough space to hold all the data or copy the data into a new construct.

If you allocated enough space for `lines` to hold all the data then it looks something like this:

```
var o = new List<string>
{
    "Hist 2368#19:00:00#20:30:00#Large Conference Room",
    "Hist 2368#09:00:00#10:30:00#Large Conference Room",
};
var lines = new string[3] { "Meeting#19:00:00#20:30:00#Conference", null, null };
// Copy the data from o to the end of lines
o.CopyTo(lines, 1); // Start a 1 to not overwrite the existing data
```

See also:

- [CopyTo(T[] array)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t69dktcd.aspx)

Otherwise if you have two different data sources that you want to pool into a new construct then I recommend using the [`Concat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb302894.aspx) method. This will combine the `IEnumerable(T)` types which you can use [`ToArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb298736.aspx) or [`ToList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb342261.aspx) to give the data the right container.

```
var o = new List<string>
{
    "Hist 2368#19:00:00#20:30:00#Large Conference Room",
    "Hist 2368#09:00:00#10:30:00#Large Conference Room",
};

var lines = new[]
{  
    "Meeting#19:00:00#20:30:00#Conference", 
}.Concat(o).ToArray();
```

Be sure you know which [container you want to use](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/221897).

Comment: +1 for keeping the original code as much as possible, combining literal construction of `new[]` and the implicit IEnumerable(T)::Concat call.

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate the values using [Enumerable.Concat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb302894(v=vs.100).aspx) :

```
lines = O.Concat(lines).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply this

```
lines = lines.Concat(o).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        List<string> myList = new List<string>()
        {
            "My First String in List",
            "My Second String in List"
        };

        string[] myArray = new string[] { "My Array First String" };

        List<string> myArrayList = new List<string>();
        foreach (var item in myArray)
        {
            myArrayList.Add(item);
        }
        foreach (var item in myList)
        {
            myArrayList.Add(item);
        }
        foreach (var item in myArrayList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
        Console.Read();
```